# "em breve" VS "dentro em breve"

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

O que é direferença entre "em breve" e "dentro em breve"?

Eu sei que "em breve" significa "soon". "Dentro em breve" significa mesma coisa?

Por exemple eu vi: **Você vai se casar dentro em breve**.

Comment: nunca ouvi falar, mas achei isso https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/dentro-em-breve/31768. Parece que é mais de portugues de Portugual. @majid. Sugiro sempre adicionar um exemplo de frase para facilitar o contexto

Comment: @Peixoto Estava lendo um livro em Portuguese Brazileiro e achei isso!
Mas como voce sugerou vou adicionar um exemplo.

Comment: sabe o título do livro? De repente, é algo mais antigo.

Comment: @Peixoto Falar...ler...escrever...português, Lima,Emma Eberlein

Comment: mesmíssima coisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem uma fonte para suporte, respondo como representante do pt-BR.

**As duas formas tem o mesmo significado** e são usadas com frequência pela mídia. Não sei afirmar se "dentro em breve" é gramaticalmente correto, mas é idiomático e de uso corrente. Em ambiente bem informal usa-se mais frequentemente: logo, logo-logo, daqui a pouco tempo, rapidinho, sem demora.

Uma consulta rápida ao Google Books mostrou que "em breve" é bem mais frequente do que "dentro em breve" (349.000 x 48.000)

Apessar disso, exemplos de "dentro em breve" abundam na web:

> - Arrisco dizer que, do jeito que as coisas andam, **dentro em breve** teremos na praça um verdadeiro “intelectuau-au”!
> - Para este último índice ainda não temos algo específico, mas certamente **dentro em breve** teremos um índice que mensure a realidade da problemática do meio ambiente e da ecologia.
> - Isto quer dizer que **dentro em breve** teremos pelo menos uma ou duas casas legalizadas para apostar online...tipo betfair.
> - Ou seja, **dentro em breve** teremos condições de atender também ao setor de óleo e gás com um produto fabricado no Brasil.
> - “Da mesma forma que surgiram celebridades do Facebook ou do Twitter, acredito que **dentro em breve** teremos também celebridades do Viber”, especula o diretor do app no Brasil.
> - **Dentro em breve** teremos também todo o nosso material feito exclusivamente para ser acessado do seu smartphone.
> - Portanto, estão de parabéns os trabalhadores novo-hamburguenses, pois **dentro em breve** será iniciada a construção de trezentas casas.

Comment: acho q estou lendo pouco e vendo pouca TV, pq nunca tinha ouvido *dentro em breve*! Realmente, achei q era restrito a Portugues de Portugual.